# Yahoo Email Login With OAuth 2.0

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, imap, yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

I have an iOS application that uses OAuth 2.0 to access a user's Yahoo email account. I am able to acquire an access token and all of its components in the form of a dictionary with the following keys: authExpires, guid, key, secret, sessionHandle, tokenExpires.

I am having difficulty with the last step: **for other email services I am able to authenticate an IMAP session via OAuth using the user's email address in the form of a string and the access token, also in the form of a string**. However in this case, because I am using the Yahoo's OAuth iOS SDK, the access token is a YOSAccessToken object with the properties I listed above. When I try to pass in this object (either as a format string or as is) I get the following error:

```
"MCOIMAPSession: [0] 1 BAD [CLIENTBUG] Invalid command or arguments".
```

I have also tried passing in the access key and the access secret and a string that concatenates all of the token components together. Everything I have tried yields the above error. I also am not sure if I should pass in the user email address (pulled from a profile dictionary) or the session handle or what.

I AM able to login directly to a Yahoo email account with IMAP (no OAuth) and this works fine - so I know my settings and account are valid.

I don't see anything in the docs that describe how to handle email logins, maybe I overlooked this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I answered my own question, it seems Yahoo does not support OAUTH for IMAP.

Comment: Related: [Do Yahoo and MS support Oauth 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6449784/1114)